# Export and Import the lookup relationship data in SharePoint 2013

Tags: list, lookup-column, blog, export, import

In SharePoint 2013 having a blog site with Posts and Comments list, these 2 lists having the lookup relation ship, I export and import from one site to another site but in comments list PostTitle column having empty, can you please help me, how to get the data with lookup relation?

Is there any way we can change and get the data using PowerShell and SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 1):

What you most likely need to do is update the **SchemaXml** property of the lookup field - the imported Posts list now should have a new ID, this change must be reflected in the field schema in the **List** attribute. There's a utility for that on CodePlex: https://splookuplinker.codeplex.com/ but you can also do the same with a PowerShell script or SharePoint Manager (http://spm.codeplex.com).

Comment: You can also find Ishai Sagi's web-based tool handy: http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/04/fixing-lookup-fields-in-list-definition.html

Comment: Thanks,Is it possible using powershell,by doing import and export we con't get the data lookup relation data,then after how we can get the data by powershell?

Comment: As soon as you set the List attribute to a valid list GUID, expect the lookups to be restored - I believe the numeric IDs of items are present in the database (you can check by querying the list via Lists.asmx) but the UI cannot show you anything as it doesn't know from which list to pull the Title by this ID.

Comment: @AlexeyKrasheninnikov: That sounds logically, and would be nice. I had the same assumptions as well, however it does not work for me (SP 2013, list exports including data). The field values get deleted on import, as long as a "parent" list having the same ID as the one referenced in the export files does not exist. Of course, the new lists are created with new IDs.